# Blender python - edit custom property of a specific object

Tags: python, properties

I am new to python. I would like to get a **custom property of an object** *(not context.object)* in a scene, for example **"Object"** *(where my custom properties are assigned)* and edit them via my custom addon - without the nessesity of selecting that object.

In other words, I would like to *change a value* via an operator in my addon, and such that the value would change in the Object's *custom property*.

My link to an object in the code:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects["Object"]
row.prop(obj, "custom_property_name")
```

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on what exactly is your question and where you are stuck ?

Comment: Hi, the operator does not display at all, there's just a label I created, but not the operator. Sometimes I get error: KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Object" not found' I wonder whether the code I wrote is right and it's a proper link to a custom property...

Comment: Are ou sure the name of your object is exactly `Object` ? The error indicates that no object with that name exists in the data

Comment: Also the correct syntax would be `row.prop(obj, '["custom_property_name"]')`

Comment: I used general naming. I fixed the line with square brackets `row.prop(obj, '["2) Path animation"]') ` and it works! Thanks a lot, that's what I've been after!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to :

Make sure your object is actually named "Object" (case sensitive)

And the correct syntax to display a custom property would be :
`row.prop(obj, '["custom_property_name"]')`